# ARP Proxy second IP of VPS to route it over Wireguard

Tags: linux, iptables, vpn, routing, wireguard

I have set up an ARP Proxy on my VPS. With this Setup, I can route incoming traffic on the second IP of my VPS over WireGuard. This should allow my Raspberry Pi at home to use the second Public IP.

I got this kind of working. Incoming Pings are forwarded over the WireGuard Tunnel to the Pi. But the Pi then tries to answer the Ping via eth0. Is there a way to fix this, so it sends the reply Packets also over the WireGuard Interface?

To show this Problem (Both on the Raspberry Pi)

WireGuard Interface:

```sh
    # tcpdump -i wg_pub
    tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
    listening on wg_pub, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
    01:35:02.796522 IP <Public ip of ping PC> > <Second VPS IP>: ICMP echo request, id 14, seq 1, length 64
    01:35:03.795359 IP <Public ip of ping PC> > <Second VPS IP>: ICMP echo request, id 14, seq 2, length 64
    01:35:04.810613 IP <Public ip of ping PC> > <Second VPS IP>: ICMP echo request, id 14, seq 3, length 64
```

Ethernet Interface:

```sh
    # tcpdump -i eth0 icmp
    tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
    listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
    01:37:11.477589 IP <Second VPS IP> > <Public ip of ping PC>: ICMP echo reply, id 14, seq 128, length 64
    01:37:12.491045 IP <Second VPS IP> > <Public ip of ping PC>: ICMP echo reply, id 14, seq 129, length 64
    01:37:13.505965 IP <Second VPS IP> > <Public ip of ping PC>: ICMP echo reply, id 14, seq 130, length 64
```

I would like to prevent using a private Subnet on the WireGuard Tunnel.

One way I got this working was to add a static route

```sh
ip route add <First VPS IP>/32 dev eth0
```

and then overwriting the default route

```sh
ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev wg_pub
```

But this has the disadvantage of routing all Internet Traffic via the VPS then.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do this with policy routing. Set up the default route for a new routing table (`123` for example) to use your WireGuard interface (`wg_pub`):

```
ip route add default dev wg_pub table 123
```

And then add a policy rule to use that new table for all packets whose source is your Second VPS IP (say it's `192.0.2.2` for example):

```
ip rule add from 192.0.2.2 table 123 priority 456
```

Priority (`456`) can be anything, only matters if you have multiple matching rules (list via `ip rule list`).